# Installation of flex and bison in ubuntu

Tags: linux

if the packages of flex and bison are not available in synaptic package manager,then how can one install flex and bison in ubuntu 10.04?
and if i download any of these packages, can you just tell me the way to use them so that they get available in synaptic package manager?

Answer (score 28):

Even better is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flex
sudo apt-get install bison

which flex  /*Sanity check to make sure flex is installed*/
which bison /*Sanity check to make sure bison is installed*/
```

Answer (score 4):

Download the src for e.g. bison from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bison/ and then do the normal

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Download `flex` from https://github.com/westes/flex/releases